# WPF - Binding to an ItemsSource AND SelectedIndex throws exception?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol, selectedindex

This code gives me an “Argument out of range” exception. When I remove the binding to the `SelectedIndex`, the `ComboBox` is populated just fine and no exception is thrown.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Is this (for some reason) not possible?

Code:

```
public class RuleMap<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Options
    {
        get
        {
            return new ObservableCollection(){"A", "B", "C"};
        }
    }

    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<RuleMap> FilterItemSource;
```

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FilterItemSource}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                 <ComboBox Width="150" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Options}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: See answer below (can't mark myself for 2 days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the ComboBox control was fundamentally broken to begin with. Thanks to this [Blog Post](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/SilverlightComboBoxControlAndDataBinding.aspx) by Rockford Lhotka, we were able to override the ComboBox control with one that could correctly bind to SelectedItem property.

Ick.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that `SelectedIndex` it is a ReadOnly Property.
Other problem can be that 0 it's not in the collection

Answer (score 1):

I think that Items are not added before selectedIndex is Binded, and since there are no item, it is showing Argument out of Range exception.

Comment: This is true, however not the solution to the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid returning a **new** collection from your Options property. You're making an assumption that WPF only accesses the property once.

But you also have the option of using a CollectionView where you're currently returning an ObservableCollection. If you're using a MVVM architecture, your ViewModel can expose the property as CollectionView and it has the notion of a "current" item.